# No puedo obtener datos de store ExtJS

Tags: extjs

estoy tratando de modificar un sistema que ya esta hecho en ExtJS y mi problema es al momento de obtener datos de un store que es el siguiente:

```
Ext.define('sistema.store.ProductionPeriodClosureAll', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'sistema.model.ProductionPeriodClosureModel',
    require: [
        'Ext.data.Store', 
        'sistema.model.ProductionPeriodClosureModel'
    ],
    
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'rest/productionPeriodClosure/list.htm'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty: 'id',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        }
    }
});
```

Con eso listo los datos de un periodo, ahora en el Controller de otra interfaz llamo a ese store:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('sistema.store.ProductionPeriodClosureAll').load();
```

Luego intento realizar un búsqueda:

```
var posicion = myStore.findBy(function(record,id){
    if(record.get('closeDate')=='2017-09-01')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

Pero el resultado me devuelve vacío, e intentado probar con `count()` haber que valor devuelve pero da lo mismo.

El objetivo de estos es comparar si una fecha existe en el store y de acuerdo a eso validar unos datos.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Primero comprueba que el api devuelve los datos que necesitas.
Luego valida que llegue una lista completa de los datos, es decir, sin filtro.
Hasta el final prueba el criterio de búsqueda. Confirma que los 2 primeros puntos están ok y muesta el resultado del JSON que retorna y hacer pruebas y te apoyo en el último punto.

Comment: Contesté la pregunta, no me había dado cuenta de que llegué un poco tarde

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás tratando de acceder a los registros del store cuando este aún no está cargado completamente, problema común porque el store es **Asíncrono**. Prueba enviandole un callback al método load para asegurarte de realizar la busqueda una ves que esté completamente cargado.

De esta forma:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('sistema.store.ProductionPeriodClosureAll').load({
    callback: function(){
     //Acciones despues de termina de cargar
    }
});
```

Espero que sea te utilidad. Saludos.